# Marionette: Close all regions

Tags: marionette

When you set up a marionette application, you usually add regions to the Marionette.Application. Is there a way to close all the regions in Marionette.Application without having to know their selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the `removeRegions` method defined in `RegionManager` to remove all regions .
To remove it from App object (instance of `Marionette.Application`) use `App._regionManager.removeRegions()`

Comment: wasn't sure about the use of _regionManager. Usually the _ indicates private. Thanks